# How to collapse a vector without adding in escape characters?

Tags: r

I have a vector of links, with surrounding html code.

```
   mylinks <- structure(list(traits = c("<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Response to amphetamines</a>", 
    "<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Bilirubin levels</a>", 
    "<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Macrophage colony stimulating factor levels</a>"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L))
```

I want to collapse these into one cell, separated by "; ".  However, when I run:

```
list_collapsed <- paste0(mylinks, collapse = "; ")
```

It prints out:

```
list_collapsed
[1] "c(\"<a href=\\\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">Response to amphetamines</a>\", \"<a href=\\\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">Bilirubin levels</a>\", \"<a href=\\\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">Macrophage colony stimulating factor levels</a>\")"
```

Where it prints out escape characters.  How do I adjust this code so that it prints out literally what was said in each cell, rather than including additional escape characters?  ie:

```
[1] "<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Response to amphetamines</a>"; "<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Bilirubin levels</a>"; \"<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Macrophage colony stimulating factor levels</a>"
```

Comment: You need to specidy the column. Try `paste(mylinks$traits, collapse = ';')`

Comment: The additional backslashes are R escaping single backslashes. If you use `cat(list_collapsed)` you get the desired output,

Comment: That worked!  If you want to post it as a solution I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer specifically to column `traits`:

```
paste0(mylinks$traits, collapse = "; ")
[1] "<a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Response to amphetamines</a>; <a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Bilirubin levels</a>; <a href=\"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1234567\" target=\"_blank\">Macrophage colony stimulating factor levels</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
paste0(print(mylinks), collapse = "; ")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(mylinks$traits, collapse = "; ")
```